# Kibana: Traffic Light visualization broken on 5.5.0

Tags: kibana

The traffic light visualization doesn’t work with Kibana 5.5.0.
(Refer: https://github.com/sbeyn/kibana-plugin-traffic-sg/issues/6)

This should be a show-stopper for all those who are already using it. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Fork of Nico:
https://github.com/Nico-DF/kibana-plugin-traffic-sg.git

Change all versions in package.json to your kibana version.